# Power bi code move to SQL as precalculation

Tags: sql, powerbi

I want to move some calculation from Powerbi to SQL so only the results will be in Powerbi

Powerbi code:

```
MoM = 
IF(
    ISFILTERED('X'[Year-month]),
    VAR __PREV_MONTH =
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('X'[stock_value_current]),
            DATEADD('X'[Year-month].[Date], -1, MONTH)
        )
    RETURN
        CALCULATE(SUM('X'[stock_value_current])-__PREV_MONTH)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a headline figure, and that [year-month] is a date column:

```
select sum(t1.stock_value_current) - sum(t2.stock_value_current)
from MyTable t1
left join MyTable t2
on t2.[year-month] = dateadd(mm,-1,t1.[year-month])
where t1.[year-month] = @MyDateParameter
```